# combine products with same category in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contains products and their categoryID, some of products have the same category. the output of the array is below

```
array (size=5)
  'categoryID' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '2' (length=1)
  'name' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'HP Player' (length=9)
      1 => string 'Android App' (length=11)
      2 => string 'TV' (length=2)
  'price' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '600' (length=3)
      1 => string '111' (length=3)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)
  'qty' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '22' (length=2)
      1 => string '22' (length=2)
      2 => string '222' (length=3)
  'exprice' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '13200' (length=5)
      1 => string '2442' (length=4)
      2 => string '222' (length=3)
```

I want to combine the products that have same categoryID, the output should be like below:

```
array (size=2)
  => 0 array
  'categoryID' => 
    array 
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
   'name' => 
    array 
      0 => string 'HP Player' (length=9)
  'price' => 
    array 
      0 => string '600' (length=3)
  'qty' => 
    array 
      0 => string '22' (length=2)
  'exprice' => 
    array 
      0 => string '13200' (length=5)

   => 1 array
  'categoryID' => 
    array 
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
   'name' => 
    array 
     0 => string '2' (length=1)
     1 => string '2' (length=1)
  'price' => 
    array 
      0 => string '111' (length=3)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
  'qty' => 
    array 
      0 => string '22' (length=2)
      1 => string '222' (length=3)
  'exprice' => 
    array 
      0 => string '2442' (length=4)
      1 => string '222' (length=3)
```

how could I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = array (
  'categoryID' => 
    array (
      0 => '5',
      1 => '2',
      2 => '2'
        ),
  'name' => 
    array (
      0 => 'HP Player',
      1 => 'Android App',
      2 => 'TV'
        ),
  'price' => 
    array (
      0 => '600',
      1 => '111',
      2 => '1'
        ),
  'qty' => 
    array (
      0 => '22',
      1 => '22',
      2 => '222'
        ),
  'exprice' => 
    array (
      0 => '13200',
      1 => '2442',
      2 => '222'
        )
    );

$cat_count = count(array_keys($arr['categoryID']));

$new_arr = array();
for($i=0;$i<$cat_count;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++){
        if($arr['categoryID'][$i] == $arr['categoryID'][$j]){
            $arr_key = array_search($arr['categoryID'][$i], $arr['categoryID']);
            $cat_exists = 1;
        }
    }
        if($cat_exists){
            $new_arr[$arr_key]['name'][] = $arr['name'][$i];
            $new_arr[$arr_key]['price'][] = $arr['price'][$i];
            $new_arr[$arr_key]['qty'][] = $arr['qty'][$i];
            $new_arr[$arr_key]['exprice'][] = $arr['exprice'][$i];            
        }else{
            $new_arr[$i]['categoryID'][] = $arr['categoryID'][$i];
            $new_arr[$i]['name'][] = $arr['name'][$i];
            $new_arr[$i]['price'][] = $arr['price'][$i];
            $new_arr[$i]['qty'][] = $arr['qty'][$i];
            $new_arr[$i]['exprice'][] = $arr['exprice'][$i];            
        }
}
```

P.S :: **$arr** is input array & **$new_arr** is output(result) array!

Comment: Thanks Prashant Gadhvi it works but not all the time, I think there is a problem in $cat_exists = 1; because I get this error Message: Undefined variable: cat_exists

Comment: After $new_arr = array(); Write below code and try: $cat_exists = 0;

Comment: Thanks for your reply. still same result. the algorithm is only doesn't work if the last product has different category ID. if so, it join the last product to the previous category ID.

Comment: `array (size=5)
      'categoryID' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '5' (length=1)
      'name' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => string 'HP Player' (length=9)
          1 => string 'HP Player' (length=9)
          2 => string 'HP Player' (length=9)
          3 => string 'Android App' (length=11)
` Android App should be with categoryID 2

Comment: I din't get you. What is your desired Category_ID array that you want to input. Say currently as per your question it is:
`'categoryID' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '2' (length=1)`

Comment: Say this input. `'categoryID' => array (size=4) 0 => string '5' (length=1) 1 => string '2' (length=1) 2 => string '2' (length=1) 3 => string '5' (length=1)`

Comment: And what would be your 'name', 'price' etc arrays as in input? Say as you have below as your 'name' array currently:
`'name' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'HP Player' (length=9)
      1 => string 'Android App' (length=11)
      2 => string 'TV' (length=2)`

Comment: Say the following: `'name' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'HP Player' (length=9)
      1 => string 'Android App' (length=11)
      2 => string 'TV' (length=2)
      3 => string 'HP Player' (length=9)` Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: If categoryID is repeated say **here** 2 & 5 both are repeated, then should output have as below:
'name', For 2:
`[name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Android App
                    [1] => TV
                )`
& 'name', for 5:
`[name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => HP Player
                    [1] => HP Player
                )`
If not, then how do you want your output? Please elaborate.

Comment: The output should be like this `array (size=5)
      'categoryID' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '5' (length=1)
      'name' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'HP Player' (length=9)....etc   1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'categoryID' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2' (length=1)
      'name' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'Android App' (length=11)
          1 => string 'TV' (length=2)
          2 => string 'Android App' (length=11).... etc`

Comment: Hi Parshant, it works now by set `$cat_exists = 0;` after the first loop. Thanks again I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad that you got it!! Sorry but as it's a weekend I was busy with other stuffs! :)

Comment: Thanks, Khaled & same to you! Cheers!